# How to implement Fabcebook Login in iOS with SSO for dialog prompt?

Tags: ios, dialog, single-sign-on, facebook-login

I want to implement Facebook login using dialog, not by automatic launching of the Facebook app or Safari.
Im using ARC in my project and I've compiled the script file (**build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh**), by compiling the script file, I got folders in my facebook-ios-sdk-master containing **lib->facebook-ios-sdk** and inside facebook-ios-sdk folder, I have some **.h** files, and couple of files. all that files have been dragged and dropped to the project.

Problem is how to implement Login dialog with those `.h` files and couple of files. and I don't want to login with launching Facebook native app or launching Safari in iOS. Please, is there any answer ?

Comment: How is SSO supposed to work if you use neither the Facebook app nor Safari? Where is the persistent login coming from? And why don't you want to use the official SDK login (does FB even allow other ways)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do changes in facebook_ios_static lib before compilation.
open `facebook.m` file then go to the method

```
[facebook authorize:nil];
```

and set

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

and then compile it.
So everytime, when you'll call fb login method, login page will prompt in dialog box not in safari or facebook app.

Comment: You will get sso (Dialog box hold WebView to load login page), login prompt will come at begining of the application or else if you did programatically logout and then trying to play with fb obj.

Comment: But you will have to enter your password all over again for every app, right? With SSO, you log in once, and be done with it.

Comment: @MayurBirari : Yes, you're right. I've found the answer. And thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.
It's better to use the standard thing, since the users are already used to it.

iOS6 should have already integrated with facebook, so no longer need to worry about this.

Comment: Here is the _[LINK](http://nabtech.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/facebook-ios-sdk-and-arc/)_ to easily change the code on **Facebook.m** just like @Mayur Birari mention. Just change the code and compile it inside Xcode. And here is the _[LINK](https://github.com/msealand/facebook-ios-sdk)_ that provide Facebook SDK contain Facebook.m