# How to add facebook-ios-sdk in app for login and fetch user data

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate the facebook login dialog in my app. For that i have checked the facebook developer page to integrate it.

1 - Downloaded `facebook sdk` package and installed it 
2 - added `facebook.framework` and `FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle` in my app 
3 - and use its `SessionLoginSample`

Its running and user can do login using facebook but its open in safary instead of that i want to open it in dialog box.

Answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506071/how-to-implement-fabcebook-login-in-ios-with-sso-for-dialog-prompt) says that do change in facebook.m file but my project does not have it. for that i have downloaded `facebook-ios-sdk` project from the [GITHub](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/src) and in that project from `src` folder i have copied all file in my project. Its non arc so added flag `fno-objc-arc`.

But facebook.m file does not contain that code which answer suggested to change. And also i have implemented graph `GraphApiSample` but it display error in FBLoginView.

So plz help on this topic any code or tutorial will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using? you can skip login functionality if you use social.framework (iOS 6). This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287429/get-posts-from-facebook-in-iphone-sdk/18288238#18288238

Comment: @NabeelThobani I am using ios 5 so i cant use the social framework. thanx for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the login page within your app you have to use the **FBGraphAPI** .

Comment: `GraphApiSample` isnt thats a use graph API. i dont know about that can you pinpoint any code sample

Comment: https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/blob/master/FbGraphAPI/FbGraph.h

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the web dialog, you need to specify the login behavior.

If you look in FBSession, there are many methods to open a Session, many of which will take an FBSessionLoginBehavior parameter. If you pass in FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView for the login behavior, it will force the web view dialog.